# Epson Stylus SX235W with Ubuntu 12.04 - Scanner not recognised

Tags: 12.04, drivers, usb, printing, scanner

I'm setting up a new computer running Ubuntu 12.04 and am having trouble getting the scanner on my Epson Stylus SX235W All-in-one to be recognised. I would like to be able to use the 'Image Scan! For Linux' program. The device is connected via usb.

I installed the relevant .deb files from the Epson Download Center for Image Scan!, namely

iscan-data_1.24.0-2_all.deb
iscan_2.29.2-1-usb0.1ltdl7_i386.deb

and installed them in that order, but the program wouldn't load.

An internet search suggested downloading the libsane-extras package and editing the /etc/sane.d/dll.conf file so that the relevant driver was uncommented in the list, which I did but to no effect.

I tried uncommenting the following lines

epson
epson2

I also tried to force libsane to use the scanner by adding the number obtained from a 'lsusb' terminal command (Bus 003 Device 012: ID 04b8:0885 Seiko Epson Corp) in this form

usb 0x04b8 0x0885

to the epson.conf file but nothing happened. Beyond this I don't really know what I'm doing so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

The information at - 
[Epson Scanner sx218 - Works Intermittently](https://askubuntu.com/questions/380970/epson-scanner-sx218-works-intermittently)

may help. The `/etc/sane.d/dll.conf` and `/etc/sane.d/epkowa.conf` had the correct entries when the `.deb` packages were installed.